# Powershell pipe output to command

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm trying to user PowerCLI to get a list of VMs with a certain disktype and then get the hosts that each of those VMs live on.

I can get the list of VMs with the disktype using this:

```
$vm = get-vm | Get-HardDisk -DiskType RawPhysical,RawVirtual | select parent -Unique
```

I tried running `get-vm -name $vm | select name,vmhost` to get the hosts of the VMs, but I get this error:

> get-vm : 1/18/2018 10:30:19 AM    Get-VM      VM with name '@{Parent=MY_SERVER_NAME}' was not found using the specified filter(s).
>   At line:1 char:1

How can I strip the `@{Parent=}` from the output so I can pass the results of the first command to `Get-VM`?

I've also tried using `Get-VMHost -VM $vm` but I get this error:

> Get-VMHost : Cannot bind parameter 'VM'. Cannot convert the "" value of type "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type 
>   "VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Types.V1.Inventory.VirtualMachine".

Comment: `Get-VM -VM $vm` -> `Get-VM -VM $vm.Parent`

Comment: Alternatively: `select parent -Unique` -> `select -Expand parent -Unique`

Comment: I solved it immediately after posting of course. Ansgar, I used a version of what you suggested. Thanks!

`$vm = get-vm
$disks = Get-HardDisk -DiskType RawPhysical,RawVirtual -VM $vm | select parent -Unique 
get-vm -Name $disks.parent | select name, vmhost`

Comment: Please don't edit an answer into a question. If you found the solution yourself: post it as an answer of your own (don't forget to accept it after the blocking period expires).